# Assigning values to objects attributes that don't exist

Tags: python, defaultdict

I'm doing a data mining homework with python(2.7). I created a weight dict for all words(that exist in the category), and **for the words that don't exist in this dict, i want to assign a default value**. 
First I tried with setdefault for everykey before using it, it works perfectly, but somehow I think it doesn't look so pythonic. Therefore I tried using defaultdict, which works just fine most of the time. However, sometimes it returns an incorrect value. First I thought it could be caused by **defaultdict** or lambda function, but apparently there are no errors.

```
for node in globalTreeRoot.traverse():
    ...irrelevant...
    weight_dict = {.......}
    default_value = 1.0 / (totalwords + dictlen)
    node.default_value = 1.0/ (totalwords + dictlen)
    ......
    node.weight_dict_ori = weight_dict
    node.weight_dict = defaultdict(lambda :default_value,weight_dict)
```

So, when I tried to print a value that doesn't exist during the loop, it gives me a correct value. However, after the code finishes running, when I try:

```
print node.weight_dict["doesnotexist"],
```

it gives me an incorrect value, and when incorrect usually a value related to some other node. I tried search **python naming system** or **assign values to object attributes dynamically**, but didn't figure it out.

By the way, is **defaultdict** faster than **using setdefault(k,v) each time**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a use case of `defaultdict`.

Instead, simply use `get` to get values from the dictionary.

```
val = dict.get("doesnotexist", 1234321)
```

is perfectly acceptable python "get" has a second parameter, the default value if the key was not found.

If you only need this for "get", defaultdict is a bit overkill. It is meant to be used like this:

```
example = defaultdict(list)
example[key].append(1)
```

without having to initialize the key-list combination explicitly each time. For numerical values, the improvements are marginal:

```
ex1, ex2 = dict, defaultdict(lambda: 0)
ex1[key] = ex1.get(key, 0) + 1
ex2[key] += 1
```

Your original problem probably is because you reused the variable storing the weight. Make sure it is *local* to the loop!

```
var = 1
ex3 = defaultdict(lambda: var)
var = 2
print ex3[123]
```

is supposed to return *the current value of `var=2`*. It's not substituted into the dictionary at initialization, but behaves as if you had define a function at this position, accessing the "outer" variable var.

A hack is this:

```
def constfunc(x):
  return lambda: x
ex3 = defaultdict(constfunc(var))
```

Now constfunc is evaluated at initialization, x is a local variable of the invocation, and the lambda now will return an x which does not change anymore. I guess you can inline this (untested):

```
ex3 = defaultdict((lambda x: lambda: x)(var))
```

Behold, the magics of Python, capturing "closures" and the anomalies of imperative languages pretending to do functional programming.

Comment: Just to be explicit for the OP, the two argument form of `get` allows one to specify a default value which is returned if the specified key doesn't exist in the dict.

Comment: Thank you! I think **get(key,defaultvalue)** is exactly what I was looking for. And also, thanks for explaining about "closures". I think I misunderstood its variable scoping method.

Answer (score 0):

`setdefault` is definitely what you should use to set a default value.

```
for node in globalTreeRoot.traverse():
    node.default_value = 1.0 / (totalwords + dictlen)
    node.weight_dict = {}
    # if you did want to use a defaultdict here for some reason, it would be
    #   node.weight_dict = defaultdict(lambda: node.default_value)
    for word in wordlist:
        value = node.weight_dict.setdefault(word, node.default_value)
```

Comment: Actually, it's **defaultdict(lambda :default_value,weight_dict)**. You have to give it a dict. I know that it works, but I'm trying to figure it out what's wrong here.

Comment: @RafaelJ if you give it a dict, it'll initialize that dict as part of the `defaultdict`. It's unclear why you'd want to do that. `d1 = {'key':'value'}; d2 = defaultdict(lambda: 42, d1)` after which `d2 == {'key':'value'}` and `d2['new_key']; d2 = {'key':'value', 'new_key':42}`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is something wrong with defaultdict.

```
d1 = {"a":10,"b":9,"c":8}
seven = 7
d2 = defaultdict(lambda :seven,d1)
seven = 8
d3 = defaultdict(lambda :seven,d1)
```

And the result:

```
>>> d2[4234]
8
```

I still don't understand why it works this way. As for my work, I'll stick with **setdefault**.

UPDATE:
Thanks for answering. I misunderstood how variable scoping works in Python.

Comment: Don't set `seven=8`. It's not defaultdict that is misbehaving but non-intuitive variable scoping in Python combined with inappropriate reuse of variables.

Comment: It's not even that hard to *grok* the variable scoping. `lambda: seven` is a function that returns the current value of the variable `seven`. If you wanted to local scope it, you'd have `lambda s=seven: s`, which would function correctly.

Comment: @AdamSmith that is an ugly hack to make it local, IMHO. And a behavior which has hurt me quite often, too, when I wanted default values set to a variable... Variable scoping is one of the things I hate about python...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse agreed that it's an ugly hack, but I guess we'll have to agree to disagree about the choice of where to scope the variable. I'm not sure why `foo = 3; bar = lambda: foo; foo = 4; bar()` should ever give `3`!

Comment: I'm not saying the alternative is better. But it should be explicit, and it should not require such a hack to get the other behavior.